# not able to fetch transient field from database in spring

Tags: spring, spring-data

I made a web crawler that crawls data from a website and persist data in database.Fields of database are

```
occasions
day
data
state
```

Now i added an extra field image to database and i had to set value of the images in database manually as i am not getting this field from web crawler.So i made the field image @transient in my hibernate model class

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
@Entity
@Table(name="Holidays")
public class Holidays implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6705527563808382509L;
    String day;
    String date;
    @Id
    String occasion;
    @Transient
    String image;
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    String state;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Holidays [day=" + day + ", date=" + date + ", occasion=" + occasion + ", state=" + state + "]";
    }
    public Holidays() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Holidays(String day, String date, String occasion, String state) {
        super();
        this.day = day;
        this.date = date;
        this.occasion = occasion;
        this.state = state;
        this.image=image;
    }
    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }
    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getOccasion() {
        return occasion;
    }
    public void setOccasion(String occasion) {
        this.occasion = occasion;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

}
```

Now after populating the field image i wanted to fetch this field from databse but is is showing me null.Is is due to transient property?Please guide

Comment: Transient precisely means: this field is not persistent. So, trying to read it from database doesn't make sense: it's not persistent. I don't see why that field should be transient.

Comment: i need to add an extra column to database but if i does not make it transient then no matter how many times i insert data to database,field will always be populated with null and i am not getting any value for this field in my crawler

Comment: If you don't have any image, and you're inserting a new row, what else than null could you store in the image column? If you're **updating** a row, then don't update that column. Only update the other ones.

Comment: i did it using @Column(insertable=false,updatable=false) working fine now:).Thanks a lot